# saving an EF Entity after edit

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, data-binding

I have a EF entity retrieved and bound to some UI controls using Unit of Work

```
public RowItem MyItem { get; set; }
using ( var ctx = new MyContext() )
    MyItem = ctx.MyEntity.Single( x =>  /// parms };


at a later time, the updates are saved on some user action
```

Question - how can i use the existing entity MyItem and keep it simple along the lines of

```
using ( var ctx = new MyContext() )
       MyItem.UpdateUsingContext(ctx);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, saving an object in EF is simple:

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

This saves all updated/new/deleted object in `context`.

If your objects were not created in this particular instance of `context` you should attach them before saving:

```
context.Attach(entity);
context.SaveChange();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create a new datacontext, you need to first attach your object, something like;

```
using ( var ctx = new MyContext() )
{
   ctx.Attach(entity);
   ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

If you are resuing the same context, which were used to fetch the entity from database you may simply call savechanges.